# How do i make a column in center inside a div with container class from Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have something like this

```
<div class="container">

   <div class="row">

         <div class="col-md-5 midOne">
            //...some content here

         </div>    

   </div>

</div>
```

I am new to bootstrap, i want this col with class midOne, to be centered inside  Is there i way to make this midOne div centered, without making two new divs on each side of midOne to be centered?

When i make this

```
<div class="col-md-4 emptyone">
            //...empty Div

         </div> 
<div class="col-md-4 midOne">
            //...some content here

 </div> 
 <div class="col-md-4 emptytwo">
            //...empty div two

 </div>
```

It is working, the content in midOne is centered in container div. with two empty divs on each side.

Comment: can you set up jsfiddle for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use .col-md-offset-4 with .col-md-4

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
 .midOne {
    width:41.6667%;
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  margin:auto;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="midOne">
              <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
                   </div>
    </div>
```